# Undefined variable returned

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm writing a Javascript function that will return a number as result. This is my code:

```
get_tiquete_hacienda: function (){
var myconsecutivo = 0;

            var rpc2 = require('web.rpc');
            rpc2.query({
                model: 'pos.order',
                method: 'compute_sales_bsi'
            }).then(function(res) {
                myconsecutivo = res;
                console.log('soy el otro: ' + myconsecutivo);
             });
return myconsecutivo;
}
```

If i look at the console, "soy el otro:" renders the correct value
but return myconsecutivo is undefined

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_tiquete_hacienda: function (){
var myconsecutivo = 0;

            var rpc2 = require('web.rpc');
            return rpc2.query({
                model: 'pos.order',
                method: 'compute_sales_bsi'
            }).then(function(res) {
                myconsecutivo = res;
                console.log('soy el otro: ' + myconsecutivo);
                return myconsecutivo;
             });
}

get_tiquete_hacienda().then(function (myconsecutivo) {
  // myconsecutivo is correct here
});
```

Or more succinctly:

```
get_tiquete_hacienda: function (){  
  var rpc2 = require('web.rpc');
  return rpc2.query({
    model: 'pos.order',
    method: 'compute_sales_bsi'
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log('soy el otro: ' + res);
    return res;
  });
}

get_tiquete_hacienda().then(function (myconsecutivo) {
  // myconsecutivo is correct here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value inside the “then” statement.